# JavaScript: dynamic name of POST parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, post

I end up with an undefined value when trying to output an HTTP POST parameter whose name I am trying to assemble dynamically (MEAN environment, server-side). Example:

```
var dynamicName = "surname";
console.log('value of POST parameter surname: '+req.body.dynamicName); //should refer to req.body.surname but remains undefined
```

Not even 'eval()' helps.

```
console.log(eval(req.body.dynamicName)); //still undefined
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Looks like it's not defined? Where are you defining it?

Comment: is this node? are you using a body-parser? is this inside a route? more information is needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `console.log('value of POST parameter surname: '+req.body[dynamicName]);`. By doing a dot notation, you are referring to `dynamicName` property, not the value it holds as a variable.